# What is meant by a "hyperbolic periodic orbit"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

At the end of the Wikipedia article on "hyperbolic sets" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_set) there is a reference to a periodic orbit being "hyperbolic", i.e. a periodic orbit of a diffeomorphism $f: M \to M$ with period $n$ is hyperbolic if and only if $Df^n$ at any point of the orbit has no eigenvalue with absolute value 1. I am confused by how this definition extends to flows as it seems to be related instead to periodic points. In particular, given a periodic orbit $x(t) = x(t+T)$ of a  (non-)autonomous $C^1$-vector field, what does it mean for $x(t)$ to be "hyperbolic"? An analogy with fixed points would be helpful.

Comment: Hyperbolicity of periodic trajectory can be defined via [Poincare map (or first return map)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map). With any periodic trajectory it associates a diffeomorphism of cross-section. This diffeomorphism has fixed point that corresponds to periodic trajectory itself. If this fixed point is hyperbolic, then periodic trajectory is hyperbolic too.